# Custom authentication in Meteor.js

Tags: authentication, meteor

Meteor has a great authentication system with some wonderful OAuth packages. But what if one would like to use some custom authentication mechanisms? Like LDAP, or a private OAuth server, or whatnot.

So, more specifically, what would be the best way to customize login/logout processes while still using the Meteor's authentication core, SRP protocol, etc.? Some practical examples would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customize and make your own OAuth package that works with meteor's core packages, specifically `accounts-base` quite easily.

There is already an LDAP package on atmosphere (http://atmosphere.meteor.com) that you could use, though I have not used it myself. You would add these in with meteorite if you have not already installed it.

```
sudo -H npm install meteorite
```

To make your own package there are loads of examples references to git repos with source code on http://atmosphere.meteor.com. There is also a blog post on how to do this in more detail at : http://meteorhacks.com/extending-meteor-accounts.html

- Meteor accounts-ldap - https://github.com/emgee3/meteor-accounts-ldap

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for ways to manually perform all authentication actions, I can suggest you to look into undocumented methods. Some useful method are described in [Meteorhacks](http://meteorhacks.com) blog.
Also, I've used a few undocumented methods in my TFA implementation, which you can read about in my [blog post](http://ravis.me/2014/12/02/meteor-js-two-factor-authentication/). In fact, I replaced all default authentication flow with my own, and I think that's the only way to implement something complex.

The most required method for your own auth flow are:

1. Meteor.loginWithToken
2. Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken
3. Accounts._hashStampedToken
4. Accounts._checkPassword

And, of course, you'll have to replace whole auth flow with your own Meteor method.

Comment: I'm newbie in Meteor and it is big black box for me. But your blog post is absolutely amazing. I suggest it to everyone who want some deeper knowledge about Meteor.
Very very thanks!

Voted.

Comment: Hi Ravis, the link is not working, can your blog still be found somewhere?